# How to change the place of y axis on ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

What I am trying is generate random data and then plot it with `ListPlot[]`. I started the graph in 0, but when I plot with `ListPlot` I keep getting the y-axis out of the origin.

Here is the code

```
In[42]:= data = 
  Accumulate[Join[{0}, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]]];

In[48]:= ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `DataRange`

```
data = Accumulate[Join[{0}, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]]];
ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, DataRange -> {0, 10},PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
 ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, it worked.